# round double with e in it

Tags: java

I've been trying trying to round this number to two decimal places, but I've had no luck:

```
double num = 9.792117207541878E24;
double roundedNum = Math.round(num*100)/100.0;
System.out.println(roundedNum); // it gives '9.223372036854776E16' not what I want
```

For some reason, I can round this using the same method:

```
double num = 1234.567;
double roundedNum = Math.round(num*100)/100.0;
System.out.println(roundedNum);
```

it gives me

```
1234.57
```

but I can't do the same with the first block of code. Is there a way I can get 9.80 using a similar method, I don't want to use DecimalFormat because I have not learned that yet in class.

Comment: Note the `E24` in the first number, this means the real decimal point is 24 places right of the dot you can see (the number is * 10²⁴). Even if you succeed in rounding that thing to two decimal places, it will have no visible effect on the number displayed.

Comment: @teapot418 Depends on the method used. For example `System.out.printf("%.3g", num);` will print 9.79e+24

Comment: OP, why do you expect 9.80? If anything, rounding would result in 9.79e24, not 9.80, nor 9.80e24.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that won't change 1234.567 to 1234.57 which is OP's second example. It's not entirely clear what they want.

Comment: *I've been trying trying to round this number to two decimal places, but I've had no luck:* What's your particular reason for decreasing the accuracy of the number?

Comment: Rounding to two decimal places is what you have. On the other hand rounding to two significant digits would turn the first number into 9.8e24, the second number to 1200. Which one do you want?

Comment: @teapot418 Then why the result is 9.223372036854776E16?

Comment: Ok, that's a good question: [Math.round](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) returns the closest `long` to the argument. You have exceeded the range of `long`, so this method is broken.

Comment: @teapot418 Makes total sense, totally forgot about the overflow, thanks

Comment: So, what do you want? `9.79E24` or what?  Please edit the question.

Comment: I think OP is not clear about what E24 means in this context.

Comment: You can simulate round using `Math.floor(number+0.5)` or something.

Comment: Usually, the only time it makes sense to decrease the precision of a floating point value is at presentation time, when you'd do something like `String presentationValue = String.format("%.2f", num);`. If you want a different method of rounding, including types such as up, down, ceiling, floor, half_up, half_down, half_even, unnecessary then use `BigDecimal`

Comment: @teapot418 Adding 0.5 won't make a difference for a number this large.

Comment: _"... I've been trying trying to round this number to two decimal places ..."_, the value is _9,792,117,207,541,878,000,000,000_.

Answer (score 3):

> For some reason, I can round this using the same method:

No, you can't. That's not how doubles work. You need to understand what doubles *are* to do this stuff.

### What doubles *are*.

Take out a small piece of paper. Then take a pen.

Now write me down, **exactly**, the value in decimal notation of how many kilos of peas you take, when I tell you to open a 1 kg bag of peas, and take precisely one third of it out.

You'll find that this task is, in fact, mathematically, **utterly impossible**. You'll write down 0.333333, and then you run out of space.

However, if I do the same thing but I ask you to take one fifth of the peas, you'll be able to do it no problem: `0.2` goes on your piece of paper and voila.

This is kinda obvious, mathematically: There's a finite amount of numbers you can express within the confines of a small piece of paper, but there are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone between - and + infinity, which is what `double` **oversimplified** says it can represent.

**This introduces the idea of blessed numbers**: *Some* numbers can be expressed perfectly on your piece of paper (such as one fifth), but some numbers cannot.

### What are you talking about? I *want* to round!

Ah, but, you're rounding in base 10 - decimal. Computers store stuff in base 2 - binary.

The reason 'one third' isn't blessed, but 'one fifth' is blessed, is that decimal is a 10-based system. 5 fits 'nicely' in 10, so it's doable. 3 does not fit nicely into 10, so it isn't.

This explains why 8 does work (8 is, broken down into prime factors, 2 times 2 times 2, and 2 fits nicely in 10, so this works), and why 7 doesn't (one seventh is also not something you can write down **precisely** on a piece of paper). 14 wouldn't work either (breaks down to 2 times 7), 60 doesn't (60 is `5*3*2*2` - if the breakdown contains any prime that doesn't "fit" in 10, i.e. anything except 2 or 5, you can't do it).

Binary is even more restrictive: The only factor is 2. So any number whose divider breaks down to factors of only 2 'works' and is **perfectly** representable as a double, **but everything else simply isnt**.

### You're joking

No. Run this code. I strongly suggest you actually do it to really internalize this bizarre aspect of doubles:

```
public void proofOfWeirdness() {
  double v = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
  System.out.println(v == 1.0);
}
```

This prints `true`, right? 10 * 0.1 is.. obviously 1.0, so of course it would.

**Run it**. It prints `false`! - because one tenth, perfectly writable in our decimal system (it's `1/(2*5)`, and 2 and 5 are the 'safe' divisor primes), **it isn't perfect in `double` math**, because only 2 is a 'safe' divisor in binary. And the tiny litle error introduced is enough to make this `false`.

It's identical to me asking you to write one third on a note, and then do it two more times, and then me asking you to add up the numbers on your 3 notes. You won't tell me 1. No, if you did it right, you'll tell me it sums to 0.9999999. Which isn't, quite, 1.0.

### So.... ?

That means 'Math.round(double * 100) / 100` **is hogwash**. No, it doesn't. The number you end up with is NOT exactly 9.80. That's not a blessed number in double parlance.

So why does it **seem** to work?

Because almost all doubles (all but those who so happen to hit a 'blessed' number) look like total garbage if you were to print their exact value. You'd end up with *a lot* of 5.999999999999999999999875 instead of 6es, and that's annoying, so:

**`System.out.println` out of the box does some very basic rounding**. And that makes it *seem* like your `Math.round(x * 100) / 100` code works. It only 'works' when that exceedingly basic rounding gets lucky, so to speak. And it only does that for quite small numbers.

### e24.. oof you're really out there now - DANGER, HERE BE DRAGONS

doubles use 64-bit for storage, which means by fundamental mathematical properties, that there can be only at most `2^64` blessed numbers. Sure, 'one third' did not fit on your little note. But writing out a 24-digit humongous number *also* does not fit on a tiny piece of paper. The same applies to doubles. This is so large, it doesn't really fit. Doubles are a little smarter than that, but note that 2^64 is 1.8e19 more or less (a 19-digit number). So how can doubles seemingly store 10e24?

Well, those blessed numbers aren't equally distributed along the number line. The gaps between blessed numbers increases as you move away from 1.

Around 2^52 (4.5e15), **the gap between representable (blessed) doubles is larger than 1**. In other words, not every integer value is even representable. Let's try it!

```
double v = Math.pow(2, 56) + 1000;
double w = v + 1.0;
System.out.println(w == v);
```

This should, obviously, print `false`, right? We're asking if some number is equal to that same number + 1 which obviosuly can't possibly be true.

**But, that prints `true`**. Because all double math silently rounds to the nearest blessed number.

Hence, *here be dragons*. The number you're seeing is quite rounded. Of course, in `1.245e24` notation, that's the same as `1245000000000000000000000` - we're only looking at the most significant digits.

### Okay, so how DO I round this thing?

As I said, you can't - not in `double` math. But what you *can* do, is print it rounded. That's no problem, and presumably what you want. We have a tool for that in java, string format (and `printf` is just a special form of that, that prints it instead of giving you a string):

```
double v = 1.23456789e24 + 10000000;
System.out.println("NOT ROUNDED: " + v);
System.out.println("BETTER: " + String.format("%.4g", v));
```

The `g` means: Round to 4 digits after the decimal point, and use scientific notation (that `e` thing). You can't not use scientific notation here - as explained above, only the first ~15 or so digits have any hope of being accurate, the remaining digits are arbitrary rounding noise.

### I need perfection though!

Well, you can have that - look at the API of [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). But, a few caveats:

- BigDecimal is hundreds of times slower.
- BDs take more and more memory to be able to represent without error.
- You still can't ask a BD to calculate one divided by three, because it'd take infinite memory. Hence, you can't divide BDs unless you get lucky (it's decimal-based, so, only divide by stuff that breaks down in prime factors of only twos and fives), or you tell BD to round.

### A note about currencies

Because of those tiny errors, **do not** use doubles to represent currencies. Use `long`, storing atomic units (so, satoshis for bitcoin, yen for yen, cents for dollars and euros, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

The double value you want to round is actually really huge. Written in plain decimal notation: `9792117207541878000000000.0`

(As you can see, it is already a number without decimals. So rounding it to two decimal digits should not do any change.)

However, the JavaDoc of `long Math.round(double value)` says:

> Returns the closest **long** to the argument, with ties rounding up.

In your case, the double value is by far larger than the largest possible long value, which is `Long.MAX_VALUE`, or `9223372036854775807`. So the result of `Math.round(num * 100)` is the closest `long` value, i.e. `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

If you now divide this result (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) by `100.0`, you get `92233720368547758.07`, or in scientific notation:
**`9.223372036854776E16`**.

#### Possible solution

Avoid the conversion to *long* by using another rounding method offered by the `Math` class: `double Math.rint(double value)`:

> Returns the double value that is closest in value to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

So this computes the correct value:

```java
double num = 9.792117207541878E24;
double roundedNum = Math.rint(num * 100.0d) / 100.0d;
System.out.println(roundedNum); // 9.792117207541878E24
```

However, you might still get into (other) troubles, as the double data type is not able to store such large numbers with a precision at decimal digit level. For details see the [answer of rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77538998/993742).

So I also suggest to use `BigDecimal` in case such precision is really required:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("9.792117207541878E24");
BigDecimal roundedNum = num.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(roundedNum.toPlainString()); // 9792117207541878000000000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The  number **9.792117207541878E24** is basically 9.792117207541878 * 10<sup>E24</sup>

```java
double num = 9.792117207541878E24;
double roundedNum = Math.round(num*100)/100.0;
```

Round() rounds the fraction part but it doesn't have any when you will evaluate 9.792117207541878 * 10<sup>E24</sup>

> The round() method rounds the specified value to the closest int or
> long value and returns it. That is, 3.87 is rounded to 4 and 3.24 is
> rounded to 3.

You can read more here: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/library/math/round

Comment: You just repeat the code shown in the question, and say why it doesn't work, but you don't actually answer the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There *is* no answer to the question. It can’t be done.

Comment: @user207421 It can be done with a lot of work, but there is no simple solution.